# FQL fails to return event data after timezone migration

Tags: timezone, facebook-fql

As described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/), after the timezone migration, these changes apply

Before 'events_timezone' migration:

- start_time and end_time fields were UNIX timestamps in Pacific Time.
- Example: '1341453600' to represent July 4th, 2012 at 7PM.
- **end_time was always defined.**

After 'events_timezone' migration:

- start_time and end_time fields are ISO-8601 formatted strings.
- **end_time may be null if none was specified.**

I used the following query to query the end times per event that's happening in the user's social network.

```
SELECT eid, end_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE start_time > '2012-08-27' AND uid IN (SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))) LIMIT 5000.
```

This query worked before the timezone migration, but it fails to return any data with the timezone migration enabled. I highly suspect this is **because at least one event has an end_time of null.**

How do I overcome this issue, and get the end_dates for most events anyway?
I wouldn't mind having a null-value for an event or two, but I want my data to be as accurate as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Your suspicion seems to be right – if I test your query without selecting the end_time column, I’m getting data, but not when I keep it in. I’d say this is definitively worth a bug report … https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

It seems like adding a simple

```
AND end_time != ''
```

did the trick

the code is now

```
SELECT eid, end_time FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE start_time > '2012-08-27' AND uid IN (SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))) AND end_time != '' LIMIT 5000
```

However, I'm now still getting less events than before. In order to achieve the same results, I will have to write a second query to get the events without an end time